# Adding two values in NSPredicate

Tags: swift, realm

Is there any way to add two variables inside `NSPredicate` which is going to be interpreted well by Realm DB ?

```
let value = 100

NSPredicate(format: "property + nextProperty >= %d", value1)
```

It is going to crash with :

```
'Invalid predicate', reason: 'The 'add:to:' function is not supported.'
```

There is a `@sum` command which:
returns the sum of the objects in the collection based on the property.

Is that same as "+" ? And how the syntax going to look ? There is no example in Realm doc for this property. Only for `@avg` which is pretty clear.
[Link to docs](https://academy.realm.io/posts/nspredicate-cheatsheet/)

Comment: You cant do that, reference realm queries document to more clear https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries

Comment: Realm's filter method uses plain `NSPredicate`s, so you can only do what's supported by `NSPredicate`s, which are well documented all over the internet, you don't necessarily need Realm's docs for that. However, what you are looking for is not feasible.